# How to get forloop.counter inside two forloops

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have a for loop inside another for loop and im trying to get the index (forloop.counter) from the inner loop. Django is for some reason giving me only the outer index.

```
{% for category in categories %}
 {% for product in products %}
  {% if product.category.name == category.name %}
   <p>This is the amount of products inside this category: {{ forloop.counter }}<p>
  {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Please share your models. You should not implement a counter like this, it is not efficient (requires iterating over every combination), and furthermore it does not give you the *number* of products, only the "rank" (as in at what location of `product` it has a link to the category).

Comment: A side note, wouldn't it make more sense to organise the products by categories in some data structure? (eg a dict). This way your code will be way more efficient than O(len(categories) * len(products))

Comment: @DeepSpace: normally Django handles this already effectively: if you fetch the `Category`s, you can let it fetch the related `Product`s, and it will make use of a dictionary to do "joining" and thus generate a list of products per category. This will then only take two queries to the database.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem im not really putting the <p> tag there. I need the counter of the products loop for a js function that only showes the first 2 elements.

Comment: @DeepSpace thanks for the info but i think this would be overkill. There is only a few products and categories.

Comment: @2567910: that would really be inefficient. It here iterates over the *combination* of the products and categories. With 10 categories and 100 products, this is already quite inefficient, especially since the template engine is not efficient in the first place. Furthermore even if efficiency was not a problem, then it does not belong in the template, since a template deals with *rendering logic*, not *business* logic, it thus should be concerned with *what* it is rendering, only presenting data in a nice way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use forloop.parentloop to get to the outer forloop, so in this case {{forloop.parentloop.counter}}. {{forloop.counter}} gives me the inner loop already.

Comment: This is a better tip

Comment: @amirmohammad I disagree, this work should be preferentially done in the view, not the template, hence my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Return to the category view (e.g. in views.py) and add an annotation:

```
from django.db.models import Count
categories = Category.objects.annotate(num_products=Count('product'))
```

Remember to include the annotation in this view's context:

```
context.update({'categories': categories})
return render(request, 'myapp/categories.html', context)
```

Now, tweak your template to show the counts:

```
{% for category in categories %}
 <p>This is the amount of products inside this category: {{ category.num_products }}<p>
{% endfor %}
```